# Centos7 :: Error unpacking rpm package httpd-2.4.6-40.el7.centos.1.x86_64

Tags: apache, docker, dockerfile, centos7

I have to build an Image Docker for the solution of my company.
This Image have to contains some dependencies and have to based on centos7. Among these dependencies, there is httpd.

So, I built an image of CentOS 7 with systemd with this Dockerfile according to these explainations : https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/

My centos7/Dockerfile

> ```
> FROM centos:centos7
>
> ENV container docker
>
> RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; \
> do [ $i == systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
> rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
> rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
> rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
> rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
> rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
> rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
> rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
>
> RUN yum -y install deltarpm && yum clean all
> RUN yum -y update && yum clean all
> RUN yum -y install vim wget tar && yum clean all
>
> VOLUME ["/sys/fs/cgroup"]
>
> CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
> ```

And I push this image on my repository "agilium/centos7"
And I wrote an other Dockerfile for httpd according to the same explainations :
My httpd/Dockerfile

> ```
> FROM agilium/centos7
>
> RUN yum -y update && yum clean all
> RUN yum -y install httpd; yum clean all; systemctl enable httpd.service
>
> EXPOSE 80
>
> CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
> ```

And I have this error when I built my image :
[Error unpacking rpm package httpd-2.4.6-40.el7.centos.1.x86_64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECFt2.png)

I also tried to localinstall the rpm package, but with the same error, like this :

> ```
> COPY ./install/* ./install/
> RUN yum -y localinstall ./install/httpd-2.4.6-40.el7.centos.1.x86_64.rpm
> ```

I search for solutions and I find an issue on github (issue #461) but it seems there was no solution found and the problem has solved itself. =/

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried `docker pull centos:centos7`? From the issue you mentioned it looks like it was an issue with the image. I can build your Dockerfile just fine with the latest version (I pulled right before building it).

Comment: I just noticed I made a mistake in my post. I forgot to mention that I pushed the first image on a repository and I used this image to build my second image. I have edited my post to correct myself.
And I'm going to try your solution ;)

Comment: So, I just tried your solution and I made `docker pull centos:centos7` before building my image, not with `FROM agilium/centos7` but with `FROM centos:centos7`. I have the same error at the same time.
If the problem can come away, this is my building line:
`docker build --force-rm=true --pull=true --tag="agilium/centos7_httpd" -f Dockerfile "$(pwd)"`

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure on what is going on then. I can build both of your images fine (building both from `centos` and building the second from the first). Is it possible for you to try building on another system and see if that behaves differently?

Comment: I looked for a solution and it seems the problem comes from I'm building and running a centos7 image on an ubuntu 15+ (16 for me) host system. It seems there is a solution on the config of docker, but I haven't tried for the moment. I'll look today. If I failed to correct the problem, I will change my host system.

Comment: I found the problem and a solution ! 
The problem was I had my Docker Storage Driver configure with "aufs". I just had to change the Storage Driver to "devicemapper". Apparently it's a problem on Ubuntu 15 and more and some Debian distributions.

Comment: Changing from aufs to devicemapper just saved my butt. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem try from Centos 6, i tried to go on devicemapper instead of aufs and my Docker crashed and i wasn't able to restart it or whatever...

I did a Dockerfile which work actually, at least until you're into the container:

```
    FROM centos:6

    RUN yum -y update \
    && yum install -y vim \
    && yum install -y httpd \
    && yum install -y mysql \
    && yum install -y php

    EXPOSE 80 443 3306

    CMD service httpd start \
    && clear \
    && bash
```